# Python graph x axis frequency control

Tags: python, graph

[image]

I want to make the x axis of the graph the same as below.

[image]

Ignore the color, I just want the x axis frequency to be in increments of 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the `xticks` from the first plot just use:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
xticks = ax.get_xticklabels()
```

Then apply it to the other plot with

```
ax2 = df.plot(...)
ax2.set_xticklabels(xticks)
```